# How to tell if scope has been destroyed

Tags: angularjs, scope, destroy

I'm putting stuff into a queue and processing them one by one. The stuff may belong to an AngularJS scope. If the scope it belongs to has been already destroyed by the time I get to it, I want to skip processing it. (The user has navigated away from the UI that would display the result, so there is no point computing it.)

One option is this:

```
function enqueue(stuff, scope) {
  queue.push(stuff);
  scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    queue.discard(stuff);
  });
}
```

But I feel like this is somewhat heavy-weight. It adds an event handler for each "stuff". (I would also need to remove this event handler when I dequeue the item.) I feel it would be better to check if the scope has been destroyed at the time when I dequeue an item.

```
function process(stuff, scope) {
  if (scope.$destroyed) { // Fictional API.
    return; // Skip processing, scope is already gone.
  } else {
    ... // Actually process "stuff".
  }
}
```

`scope.$destroyed` is made up, but I'm looking for something similar. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even couple the `scope`-concept (that is a construct of Angular to hold the ViewModel) with "processing" items (that feels like should belong to the Model)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. These items are abandoned and will never be looked at. Should I still process them to satisfy some Model-View ritual?

Comment: No, but the state of "abandonment" should be reflected with the item, not indirectly via the scope construct. So, whatever caused the scope to destruct, I would think, should also cause the item to be marked as abandoned.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do that? The abandonment happens to the scope. I've got to somehow propagate it to the item. That cannot be done without the coupling that you seem to argue against. Or can it?

Comment: Well, that's why I was inquiring why that happened. There is no context in the question as to what causes the scope to be destroyed, so difficult to answer in abstract terms

Comment: Ah, got it! I took your question as a critique of what I'm doing, sorry. I've added the explanation to the answer: the scope is the UI that will display the result. So if the scope is destroyed, the user has navigated away from that UI and will not see the result. We can skip computing it then. (Typically at this point we have a bunch of new stuff to process from the new scope.)

Comment: Well, it was also a critique :)  If you're using `ui.router`, you can use the `.onExit` callback to mark the respective items as abandoned. But if you insist, `scope.$$destroyed` is the flag to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$scope.$$destroyed` flag to check if the scope is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks! It's a 5-year-old question, but actually we still use Angular 1 in a project, so this is great to know. I was so close in my "fictional API" too! :)